# Byobu Systemd Error with ownership

Tags: ubuntu, bash, tmux, systemd, byobu

Trying to run

> 

```
#!/bin/sh
# byobu_launcher.sh ver 20170915122301 Copyright 2017 alexx, MIT Licence ver 1.0

byobu new-session -d -s $USER

# mongod
byobu new-window -t $USER:1 -n 'MLT'
byobu send-keys "/home/username/scripts/mlt.sh" C-m
```

I'm using this template with the correct info put in

```
.
```

> [Unit] Description=byobu
>
> [Service] 
>   ExecStart=/root/scripts/byobu.sh Restart=always
>
> [Install] 
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

After starting the service I get this error

**Apr 30 14:36:29 ubuntu byobu.sh[4141]: Cannot run byobu because [] does not own []

Apr 30 14:36:29 ubuntu byobu.sh[4141]: Cannot run byobu because [] does not own []

Apr 30 14:36:29 ubuntu byobu.sh[4141]: Cannot run byobu because [] does not own []**

Not sure how to fix or change the ownership.

Strangely it works on rc.local, but I think getting it to work on Systemd would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `$USER` variable but `systemd` has not set it. It only set when you use the `User=` directive.

If you want to run your service as root, then you would add `User=root` to your `[Service]` section.

Related documentation for this in [Environment Variables in Spawned Processes](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20variables%20in%20spawned%20processes) in the `systemd.exec` man page.

Comment: Thanks so much. I needed to add your part and another variable called

Comment: Thanks so much. I needed to add your part and another variable called. RemainAfterExit=yes. The code works with what I have below.

Answer (score 0):

This code works now

[Unit]
Description=MFC Byobu
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/scripts/byobu.sh
User=root
Restart=always
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target